# Why can't Xcode 4 find my .h files during a build?

Tags: xcode4

I have a project that won't build because the compiler (?) can't seem to find the .h files.  I have tried using the full path, relative path and setting the Project Search Paths (both Header and User Header) and nothing seems to work.  What I find very strange is even with the full path it gives an error: **No such file or directory** (the file does indeed exist in the specified path).

What could be the problem?

import statements:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <zxing/common/Counted.h>
#import <zxing/Result.h>
#import <zxing/BinaryBitmap.h>
#import <zxing/Reader.h>
#import <zxing/ResultPointCallback.h>
```

Headers are located in:

```
/Users/rolfmarsh/iPhoneCodeLibrary/BarcodeLibrary/zxing-1.6/cpp/core/src/zxing
```

Header search path is:

```
$(inherited)
"$(SRCROOT)/zxing/common"
```

and

```
/Users/rolfmarsh/iPhoneCodeLibrary/BarcodeLibrary/zxing-1.6/cpp/core/src
```

Full path of the include files:

```
/Users/rolfmarsh/iPhoneCodeLibrary/BarcodeLibrary/zxing-1.6/cpp/core/src/zxing/Result.h
```

Comment: please post the relevant `include` statement(s), your include path settings, the exact location of the headers on your system.

Comment: @Spokane: edit your question, don't even try to post code in comments.

Comment: import statements:

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <zxing/common/Counted.h>
#import <zxing/Result.h>
#import <zxing/BinaryBitmap.h>
#import <zxing/Reader.h>
#import <zxing/ResultPointCallback.h>

Headers are located in: 
/Users/rolfmarsh/iPhoneCodeLibrary/BarcodeLibrary/zxing-1.6/cpp/core/src/zxing

Header search path is:
$(inherited)  and
"$(SRCROOT)/zxing/common"

Comment: please see my previous comment: edit your question with the information, and include the _full path_ of the include files you're trying to include and what SRCROOT is

Comment: How do I find the contents of SRCROOT?

Answer (score 3):

I also had quite a bit of pain with ZXing's dependencies. Here's some tips that will hopefully be of assistance to others with similar issues.

This line does an import:

`#import <zxing/common/Counted.h>`

For the compiler to find `Counted.h`, the header search path must be specified.

Now, because the `import` statement will look for `Counted.h` relative to two subfolders `zxing/common`, we need to give it the parent folder of `zxing`.

In this case, the parent folder is going to be something like:

`/ .. my full path here ../cpp/core/src/`

So, under the `src` directory you'll find `zxing`.

How do we configure this in Xcode? Best to do it relatively. Otherwise, the project will fail on a different user's machine.

To do this, we specify a path relative to the project directory. As follows:

`$(PROJECT_DIR)/../cpp/core/src`

That goes in the Header Search Path of Build Settings for the ZXingWidget target.

The crucial thing with this header path stuff is to specify the *relative* directory to search from. In our case, we specify search relative to `$(PROJECT_DIR)`. That variable specifies the directory of our subproject `ZXingWidget`.

Other caveats. Be careful to specify these in the build settings of your target. If you do it at project level you'll still need to specify it at target level using the `$(inherited)` variable.

Also, don't forget that the build transcript can be very useful. Look at the header paths included with the `-I` flag.

As a general debugging technique, I like to specify the absolute path in my settings. That gives a clean build and I know that the files can be included, and where they definitely are. Having done that I then use the `$(PROJECT_DIR)` to specify a relative path.

Answer (score 3):

I am posting this in order to make things simple for newbies like me that are integrating zxing qr reader in their projects and to bring closure to a couple of threads related to zxing integration.

1.
Main thing - Be absolutely sure you have the latest version.

> http://zxing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

[By now, January 18th, you will have no more issues with that zxing/common/ folder. Easiest fix for this: get the latest code!]

2.
Go to zxing -> iphone -> ZXingWidget.

> Drag ZXingWidget.xcodeproj file and drop it onto the root of your Xcode project's "Groups and Files" sidebar.

[you should now have ZXingWidget.xcodeproj listed there and it has to drop down and list it's content]

3.
In the same place, project navigator, select:

> Your project file - > Targets -> 'your project name' -> Build phases -> Link binary with libraries.
>
> You should find a folder named 'Workspace'. Add 'libZXingWidget.a' from within.

4.
Still in  Build phases, expand Target Dependencies and add ZXingWidget.

5.
Select Build Settings and search for Header Search Paths. 
You need to add 2 records to Header Search Paths. You do not need to associate values to User Header Search Paths. You achieve this by double clicking the column on the right. A small popover window will apear. Use the + button to add the first record. Add:

> ../zxing/iphone/ZXingWidget/Classes

Now use the + button to add the second record. Add:

> ../zxing/cpp/core/src

These are the values I use. These values work because I use the same folder to host both my project and the zxing folder.

[Be sure to refer your folder properly in case you decide to have a different file structure.]

6.
Go back to Build Phases and add the following ios frameworks required:

> AVFoundation
>
> AudioToolbox
>
> CoreVideo
>
> CoreMedia
>
> libiconv
>
> AddressBook
>
> AddressBookUI

7.

> Create a set of files (.h&.m) and change it's .m extension to .mm

8.
Test the integration by including the following in the file previously created:

```
#import <ZXingWidgetController.h>
#import <QRCodeReader.h>
```

At this point you should run into missing files only if you are not running the latest version. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you need to scan anything else other than qr codes I recommend looking into ZXingObjC - same path I took. 

https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC

Comment: Works like a charm!  It would be nice to not have to be dependent on a specific location for the ZXingWidget source code.  It would be ideal to just build ZXingWidget separately, and copy the necessary header files and library archive into the app project.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to check:
- file permissions
- can you build from the command line using xcodebuild?

Comment: I started over, fresh code, and now it works... thank you both for your suggestions.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I went over many blog posts on how to fix this. This one helped me well.

http://alwawee.com/wordpress/2011/12/01/zxingwidgetcontroller-h-not-found-zxing-installation-problem-solution/

The problem was that header search paths were not properly defined. 
So I...

1) Downloaded zxing 2.1

2) From the download I copied: iphone, cpp, objc and readme and pasted in a folder names "zxing"

3) I added the new folder "zxing" to my project (on my mac) not to the xcode app.

4) From the created folder zxing I dragged the zxingwidget.xproje to my xcode project

5) I followed all the steps you find in all the blogs

**KEY TO SOLVE THIS**

6) I followed this steps for xcode errors https://stackoverflow.com/a/14703794/1881577

7) I followed this steps for header path file errors http://alwawee.com/wordpress/2011/12/01/zxingwidgetcontroller-h-not-found-zxing-installation-problem-solution/

**IMPORTANT NOTE: I had to do follow step 7) twice, I had to select the project target and assign header paths, and I had to select the project project and assign header paths.**

8) Build zxingwidget project (from the scheme select options)

9) Build Run the project.

Hope this helps other people as well.