# Error : 'ZXingWidgetController.h' file not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, qr-code, zxing

I get this error and i have done everything i can. I have tried adding the relative path or the absolute path and none work. Is there anything else that i should do to get ZXing working? Also im not using ARC so is this a problem with the latest version of ZXing? I read every blog/question available but i keep getting this error and i have no idea why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  In file included from /Users/KaushiK/Projects/Projects/iOS/ZXingProjectFolder/trunk/iphone/x/QRReaderViewController.mm:10:
/Users/KaushiK/Projects/Projects/iOS/ZXingProjectFolder/trunk/iphone/x/QRReaderViewController.h:10:9: fatal error: 'ZXingWidgetController.h' file not found
```

## import "ZXingWidgetController.h"

Comment: Steps for a clean integration at this time, January 2013: > http://stackoverflow.com/a/14404363/1188082

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the header file that it's looking for '`ZXingWidgetController.h`', make sure that the directory containing that "Header Search Paths":

1. Select you project in Xcode and go over to the "`Build Settings`" tab
2. Search for "`Header Search Paths`"
3. Make sure this field includes the directory that holds the header file you're looking for
4. Then you should be able to import it using quotes:

#import "`ZXingWidgetController.h`"

If you have this file as a part of your project in Xcode, you can also make sure that it's included in your build target:

1. Select the header file, and open up the "`Utilities`" panel on the right
2. Ensure your build target is selected under "Target Membership"

If this file is just bundled up in a framework however, then go over the the "Build Phases" tab and make sure this framework is listed under the "Link Binary With Libraries" phase. Then import it using angle brackets:

#import <ZXing/ZXingWidgetController.h>