# Linking Error with UnitTest++

Tags: unit-testing, unittest++

I am getting an odd Unit Test ++ linking error using Xcode as my ide.
Now I did set the project up with two targets. one target that will do the test the other will do nothing for now.

Note I did link the library and ran the simple working example from the tutorial.
and I compiled it using gcc 4.2.1 from macports.

"std::string::c_str() const", referenced from:
      UnitTest::MemoryOutStream::GetText() const in libUnitTest++.a(MemoryOutStream.o)
  "std::basic_ostringstream, std::allocator >::str() const", referenced from:
      UnitTest::MemoryOutStream::GetText() const in libUnitTest++.a(MemoryOutStream.o)
  "std::basic_ostream >::~basic_ostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::ostream-in-UnitTest::MemoryOutStream in libUnitTest++.a(TestRunner.o)
      construction vtable for std::ostream-in-UnitTest::MemoryOutStream in libUnitTest++.a(Test.o)
  "std::basic_ostream >::~basic_ostream()", referenced from:
      construction vtable for std::ostream-in-UnitTest::MemoryOutStream in libUnitTest++.a(TestRunner.o)
      construction vtable for std::ostream-in-UnitTest::MemoryOutStream in libUnitTest++.a(Test.o)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665457/zxing-in-xcode-4-5-and-ios-6

Answer (score 1):

Okay so all the problems went away when I switched the std library to GNU standard library rather then the llvm osx standard library. So go to build settings c++ standard library libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library)