# Error linking OpenCV and Tesseract

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, tesseract

I'm trying to using both OpenCV and Tesseract in my iPhone app.

I have no problem working with either one of them - all is compiled and linked perfectly.

But when I'm trying to work with both of them it gives me link errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)", referenced from:
  -[BTLOpenCVCameraViewController processImage:] in BTLOpenCVCameraViewController.o
"cv::_OutputArray::~_OutputArray()", referenced from:
  -[BTLOpenCVCameraViewController processImage:] in BTLOpenCVCameraViewController.o
"cv::Mat::deallocate()", referenced from:
  cv::Mat::release() in BTLOpenCVCameraViewController.o
"cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Mat const&, cv::Rect_<int> const&)", referenced from:
  -[BTLOpenCVCameraViewController processImage:] in BTLOpenCVCameraViewController.o
"cv::fastFree(void*)", referenced from:
  cv::Mat::~Mat() in BTLOpenCVCameraViewController.o
"cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::_OutputArray const&) const", referenced from:
  -[BTLOpenCVCameraViewController processImage:] in BTLOpenCVCameraViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm running iOS6.1, C++ Standard Library is set to: "Compiler Default"
Architecture is set to: armv7.

ANy ideas??

Comment: You obviously are trying to build a simulator version (i386) - are both of your libraries also built for the simulator?

Comment: OpenCV library must be run on iPhone device since it opens the camera-live-view, but Tesseract can run on simulator.

But, but If I comment the code of the OpenCV then Tesseract compiles and links perfectly, and vice versa. the problem is when trying to link them both together.

Comment: Yes, each one of them runs without any problem.

Comment: Ok, I compiled it on device, and these are the errors I receive:


    Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error()     const", referenced from:
      std::__1::vector<cv::Vec<int, 128>,    std::__1::allocator<cv::Vec<int, 128> > >::__append(unsigned long) in opencv2(matrix.o)
      std::__1::vector<cv::Vec<int, 64>,   std::__1::allocator<cv::Vec<int, 64> > >::__append(unsigned long) in opencv2(matrix.o)
      std::__1::vector<cv::Vec<int, 32>, std::__1::allocator<cv::Vec<int, 32> > >::__append(unsigned long) in opencv2(matrix.o)

Comment: OpenCV needs to be compiled with: "C++ standard library" as "LLVM C++ standard libray with C++ 11 support.

Tesseract needs to be compiled with: "C++ standard library" as "Compiler default"

one library contradicts the other, how can I overcome this??

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665457/zxing-in-xcode-4-5-and-ios-6/12666175#12666175) on the subject of setting up the standard library settings of a project / subproject / library.

Comment: Make any progress on this?  I am interested in a solution too.