# Is it possible to create static library with existing thirdparty framework like metaio framework

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, xcode4.5, xcode4.6

I have a problem with static library creation, I want to create static library with existing sorce code and existing thirdparty framework like metaio framework.But when I am creating static library with out metaio framework (Third party framework) It is workin Fine. But when adding metaio framework (Third party framework) into static library It is showing a lot of errors. Is it possible or not ? Which is happining in Xcode4.5 and Xcode4.6.

**Errors Like:**

"Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "metaio::SensorsComponentIOS::getSensorComponentImpl()", referenced from: -[Tutorial5ViewController loadContent] in libmetaio.a(Tutorial5ViewController.o) "metaio::CreateMetaioSDKIOS(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&)", referenced from:  "metaio::getDeviceType()", referenced from:
      -[EAGLView enableAntialiasing] in libmetaio.a(EAGLView.o)

> ::~basic_string()", referenced from:
>         -[MetaioSDKViewController viewDidLoad] in libmetaio.a(MetaioSDKViewController.o)
>         -[Tutorial5ViewController touchesBegan:withEvent:] in libmetaio.a(Tutorial5ViewController.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" but i was created in the same architectures like arm7 and arm7s, But it is working fine with out adding metaio framework.

Comment: There is no Xcode5 or Xcode6. What are the errors you get? Give us more details!

Comment: sorry, it mean 4.5 and 4.6

Comment: Hi Till could u pls give me the solution for that

Comment: Could you give us more details like the exact error messages?

Comment: Hi Till could u pls give me the solution for that actually i'm getting errors like "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "metaio::SensorsComponentIOS::getSensorComponentImpl()", referenced from:

 -[Tutorial5ViewController loadContent] in libmetaio.a(Tutorial5ViewController.o)
  "metaio::CreateMetaioSDKIOS(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:

Comment: "metaio::getDeviceType()", referenced from:
      -[EAGLView enableAntialiasing] in libmetaio.a(EAGLView.o)
>::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      -[ARELViewController onSDKReady] in libmetaio.a(ARELViewController.o)
      -[MetaioSDKViewController viewDidLoad] in libmetaio.a(MetaioSDKViewController.o)
      -[Tutorial5ViewController touchesBegan:withEvent:] in libmetaio.a(Tutorial5ViewController.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: but i was created in the same architectures like arm7 and arm7s,But is working fine with out adding metaio framework.

Comment: @prakashios - please edit your question with the error detail vs. placing in comments.

Comment: Your issue appears to be related to the C++ Standard Library used. Please see this answer for solving the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665457/zxing-in-xcode-4-5-and-ios-6/12666175#12666175

Comment: ok, Thank you for ur suggestions Till, i will check it and then discuss with u.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely linking against the "wrong" C++ Standard Library in your project. All projects / libraries involved for building have to use the same C++ Standard Library.

For more details and for correcting the issue, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665457/zxing-in-xcode-4-5-and-ios-6/12666175#12666175).

Comment: ok, Thank you for ur suggestions Till, i will check it and then discuss with u.