# Zxing with Xcode 5.0.2

Tags: ios, xcode5, zxing

I am using the library ZXingWidget, I have an error when i try to build my project, it work on Xcode 5.0.2

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "__Unwind_SjLj_Register", referenced from:
      __ZN5zxing9BinarizerC2ENS_3RefINS_15LuminanceSourceEEE in Binarizer.o
      __ZN5zxing9BinarizerD0Ev in Binarizer.o
      __ZN5zxing9BinarizerD2Ev in Binarizer.o
      __ZN5zxing7CountedD0Ev in Binarizer.o
      __ZN5zxing12BinaryBitmapC2ENS_3RefINS_9BinarizerEEE in BinaryBitmap.o
      __ZN5zxing12BinaryBitmapD0Ev in BinaryBitmap.o
      __ZN5zxing12BinaryBitmapD2Ev in BinaryBitmap.o
      ...
  "__Unwind_SjLj_Resume", referenced from:
      __ZN5zxing9BinarizerC2ENS_3RefINS_15LuminanceSourceEEE in Binarizer.o
      __ZN5zxing9BinarizerD0Ev in Binarizer.o
      __ZN5zxing9BinarizerD2Ev in Binarizer.o
      __ZN5zxing7CountedD0Ev in Binarizer.o
      __ZN5zxing12BinaryBitmapC2ENS_3RefINS_9BinarizerEEE in BinaryBitmap.o
      __ZN5zxing12BinaryBitmapD0Ev in BinaryBitmap.o
      __ZN5zxing12BinaryBitmapD2Ev in BinaryBitmap.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool: internal link edit command failed
```

and my project framework is have these library
libiconv.dylib
CoreMedia
CoreVideo
AddressBook
AddressBookUI
AVFoundation
Foundation
UIKit
AudioToolbox
CoreGraphics

and..
Architectures is **armv7,armv7s** , Build Active Architecture Only is **NO** , Valid Architectures is **armv7 amrv7s**

Comment: Is `armv7s` also included within the build-settings of the ZXingWidget library?

Comment: Actually, it sounds a bit as if you are using a prebuilt ZXingWidget library that is not compatible with your build environment. You may simply have to rebuild matching your setup. For more, please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/12666175/91282

Comment: Yes, armv7s is in the ZXingWidget library