# PhoneGap QR Code Scanner by XZing

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova, qr-code, zxing

I am trying to get XZing running on my PhoneGap Iphone application:

After doing some researches I found this link for best instructions to install XZing to my application:

[Why can't XCode 4 find my .h files during a build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284422/why-cant-xcode-4-find-my-h-files-during-a-build/14404363#14404363)

I completed the steps and ran the app with no Errors.

Now I am trying to run the scanner and I use the BarcodeScanner test file and here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="onLoad()">
        <div class="app">
            <div id="running-bits">

<button id="scan-button">scan: ?</button>

<p>(<span id="test-count-current">?</span>
/
<span id="test-count-total">?</span>)

<p><img id="image" src="">

<p>expected text:
<br><tt><span id="test-text">?</span></tt>

</div>

<p><b id="test-done"></b>
<br><button id="start-over">start over</button>

<p>Results:
<ul id="results-list">
</ul>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
        <script src="js/barcodescanner.js"></script>
        <script src="js/phonegap-app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code for phonegap-app.js in the link below:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iPhone/BarcodeScanner/test/phonegap-app/phonegap-app.js

However, when I click on the scan button the scanner, it fails and I get this error in the Log :

BarcodeScanner failure: exception scanning: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object

Comment: Why don't you just use the BarcodeScanner plugin for iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following things:
1) Change in Cordova.plist and barcodescanner javascript file the string 'org.apache.cordova.barcodeScanner' to 'CDVBarcodeScanner'.
2) In barcodescanner.js:
a) Change Cordova to cordova
b) Comment the lines with hasResource and addResource in the beginning.

Hope this would help.

Comment: I fixed it finally and I'll upload the full project so everyone can use it