# Xcode 4.6 zXing compile error after Xcode update (4H127)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, zxing, xcode4.6

Different projects using ZXing have error after last Xcode update:

Error messages are:

1. private field 'cached_y_' is not used
2. Private field 'bits_' is not used
3. Private field 'cached_row_num_' is not used
4. Private field 'dataHeight_' is not used

Any compiler flag I have to set up?

Comment: I don't think these are errors, rather warnings.

Comment: i assume these are not errors but warnings for the fields which you might have not used within your project

Comment: Unfortunately the compiler show them as errors (red color and not yellow color as for warning) and is impossible to complete the build phase. I try to remove the "unused" variable definitions but the error appears somewhere else (variable not defined...)

Comment: This should be posted to the ZXing project page, not SO. It's always best to contact the developers directly for such an issue.

Comment: Did you ever get a fix for this? Got the same issue...

Comment: This modifications work (tested): http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/detail?r=2566#

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just add this flag

```
-Wno-unused-private-field
```

under ZXingWidget target -> Build Settings -> Other Warning Flags. Click the + button and paste the flag, clean and build again.

[image: How to set compiler flags]

(No need to remove any other flag, just ignore unused private field warning)

Comment: The best temporary fix up to this time. Thanks

Comment: if i were @Fulkron i would have accepted this answer. This is the most straight forward answer to this problem :)

Comment: This solution leaves the project clean without warnings

Comment: @txulu After fixing this i got issue from SMSAction.h file?

Answer (score 13):

Here is a workaround to get it to compile. You have remove couple compile warning flags:

Select the xzing project, build settings, look for "Other Warning Flags" and remove -Werror and -Wno-unused-parameter

[image]

Comment: Its in the section titled "Apple LLVM 4.2 compiler warning flags".  See screenshot here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/az64llbjqv326mr/llvm_compiler_warning_flags.png

Answer (score 3):

They have the project set up to treat warnings as errors.  Turn off that setting and it should compile, so you can at least run the sample code.

Also tell them so they can fix the warnings.

Comment: Are you looking at the target it's trying to compile?

Comment: OK in the subProject target there is the flag to change to avoid error messages. Hope they fix asap. tnx

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a temporary fix http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=1494 I hope for a much nicer solution soon.

Comment: Just removing the "Other Warning Flags" "-Werror" worked perfectly for me! Got only 4 warnings so far. (Which is just what Kendall Helmstetter Gelner was saying)