# Unused Entity Issue Private field 'cached_y_' is not used Xcode4.6 not an error

Tags: xcode4.6

In .h file

Getting only warnings like this

`Unused Entity Issue Private field 'cached_y_' is not used Xcode4.6 not an error only warnings`

int cached_y_;

Comment: did you find anything on this?

Comment: Here is what you looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14616402