# ZXing for Obj-C won't compile

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, zxing

I'm trying to implement the objective-c port of ZXing [here](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC) for my iOS project. I've followed all the instructions but the compiler can't find any of the linked files. Has anyone tried to implement this version? Does the readme.txt leave something out. I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure this out.

Comment: Are you compiling it as static library?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem as long as you imported all required framework.

Comment: tried it this week, and it worked. do you get any error-msg?

Comment: you tried it with the instructions in the read me? no additional steps? After I import the "ZXingObjC.h" any class when I try to build it says it can't find any of the import files from "ZXingObjC.h"

Comment: I am but I flagged all the imported files in the compiler not to use arc. I have also tried a new project from scratch that doesnt use arc to no avail.

Comment: ok. try to import only the files you need. if i remember right  you only need to import ZXCapture.h for the demo. importing ZXingObjC fails in my project too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use Cocoapods for the installation of Zebra Xing.
The last versions of Xcode added more errors to check in c++, you can also try this way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593291/xcode-4-6-zxing-compile-error-after-xcode-update-4h127) to remove this kind of checking.
You should also check:
[here](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC)